# How did the Earth Dragon Balls revive everyone killed by Frieza?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

The Earth Dragon Balls were only capable of reviving one person at a time and that too, only once. Then how did they revive Vegeta and all the Namekians on planet Namek when the dragon was asked to revive everyone killed by Frieza?

Comment: I can understand your confusion. you would think that the huge dragonballs can do more than the small ones. But nope. Earth dragon balls(Piccolo OP) can even wish an entire planet back to life whereas the namakean ones cannot.

Comment: At the beginning of the Namek Saga they said Piccolo was one of namek's more brilliant minds and made the earth dragon balls more op than the original ones on namek.

Comment: You are mixing the powers, Namekian DBs could revive any 1 individual any number of times. But the earth dragonballs could revive any number of individuals just once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um... they weren't limited to only 1 person at a time.

It was the Namekian Dragon Balls that were limited to 1 at a time.  The Earth Dragon Balls had no such restriction. In fact, they were used before to revive multiple people that Piccolo killed at the end of the Piccolo saga

<sub>Further reading : [Dragon Ball](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_%28object%29)</sub>